# How do I update browserslist?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Does browserslist update automatically or do I have to manually update it? Is there a command to force it to update?

E.g. the targets for the "last 1 version" directive would change whenever a new browser version is launched. How does my local copy of browserslist know when a new version is launched? At what point does it sync with browserslist's server? Does it update periodically, every time it's used, or only when you update the package?

The existing answers only give vague answers such as "it will always fetch the latest version" or "it will find target browsers automatically". However, it doesn't answer **when** it updates. Obviously my local version of browserslist wouldn't update as soon as a new browser version is released, there will be a delay.

Answer (score 31):

You need to run

```
npx update-browserslist-db@latest
```

Every few months to fetch the latest list of browsers.

This does two things:

- Gets the list of recently released browser versions (used by `last N versions`).
- Deduplicates¹ `caniuse-lite` npm package (in case it is used by more than one dependency at once).

¹ Deduplication essentially ensures that if `package1` depends on `caniuse-lite` version `1.0.10` and `package2` depends on `caniuse-lite` version `1.0.15`, the process will ensure that both of them use the same (latest) version - `1.0.15`.

Comment: When I run that command, I get: `browserslist: Unknown arguments --update-db.` with a list of usage options. Up until last month, I'd never seen the warning about running the update.

Comment: @WayneSmallman I still see the option in `cli.js` of browserlist https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist/blob/8b7def97edf9b734eba7ee37ebefff2fc98a7bb5/cli.js#L41 You can try installing the latest version of browserlist with `npm i browserlist@latest` first, and then try running the command.

Comment: What/where does this actually update the data?

Comment: @Slbox You can see the implementation details here: https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist/blob/17a46b41fc4f00818fd3dc956391f3f2cb4fdcc3/update-db.js, but in short it updates the lock file used by your package manager (npm in this case) and installs the \@latest version of browserlist

Answer (score 4):

I don't really know why, but none of the other solutions did the trick for me. I still had multiple `caniuse-lite` versions in my lock file.

What finally worked for me was to simply set a resolution in my `package.json` file and then run `npm install` or `yarn`.

```
"resolutions": {
  "caniuse-lite": "^1.0.30001255" // newest version as of writing
}
```

After this everything was using the newest version and my build worked as expected. You probably need to update this every once in a while, but you would need to do the same thing with `--update-db`.

Comment: The script _should_ strip out other versions of caniuse.  Did you see what happens after deleting your package lock and doing another install just to make sure you are still getting multiple versions there?

Comment: I didn't try to delete my package lock because I actually want to keep my other locks entries. But the `yarn add -W caniuse-lite` that gets run basically did nothing for me.

Answer (score 1):

IF you write `last 1 version` in your [browserlist config](https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist) then it will always fetch the latest version and you don't have to do anything.

```
  "browserslist": [
    "last 1 version",
    "> 1%",
    "maintained node versions",
    "not dead"
  ]
```

This is what the [documentation has to say about caching.](https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist#cache)

Comment: It fetches latest every time I call it, so there's no caching?

Comment: The current documentation does not say that `last 1 version` would have any effect on the caching behaviour.

Comment: You write `last 1 version` in your `package.json` or `browserlist` file. and documenation says this about it: `Browserslist caches the configuration it reads from package.json and browserslist`

Answer (score 1):

As per the [documentation](https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist#browserslist-)
All tools will find target browsers automatically, when you add the following to package.json:

```
"browserslist": [
    "last 1 version",
    "> 1%",
    "maintained node versions",
    "not dead"
  ]
```

Or in `.browserslistrc` config:

## Browsers that we support

```
last 1 version
> 1%
maintained node versions
not dead
```

[Browserslist caches](https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist#cache) the configuration it reads from package.json and browserslist files, as well as knowledge about the existence of files, for the duration of the hosting process.

To clear these caches, use:

```
browserslist.clearCaches()
```

*To disable the caching altogether*, set the `BROWSERSLIST_DISABLE_CACHE` environment variable.

Comment: What does "automatically" mean? Your answer implies it's only updated when you change package.json or .browserslistrc, which would be a problem